# 400 Bad Request connecting with SPOService using PowerShell 7.2

Tags: powershell, error

I have beat my head against the wall and read MANY posts around the Internet. I am using PowerShell 7.2 and have installed and updated `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell`.

Using a simple `Connect-SPOService -Url https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com` always results in a popup asking for creds and then  results in (400) Bad Request.

I've verified am using the correct URL (opens great in a browser) and a login name with proper rights (Global admin account used to admin SharePoint).

Would someone be ever so kind and explain what it is I'm doing wrong? I'm a newbie to PowerShell connections to SharePoint. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

The `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell` (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell/) module requires *Windows* PowerShell. You can use up to (Windows) PowerShell 5.0.

Comment: Thank you Trever. This is something I did not know. I ran into a post talking about using -UseWindowsPowerShell (minus in front) for compatibility. I'm afraid that may have tainted my thoughts and searches. Do you by chance know what adding the minus is meant to do? Thank you so much for your quick response. Have a great day!

Answer (score -2):

The proposed solutions include:

1. Check the Submitted URL
2. Clear Browser Cache
3. Clear Browser Cookies
4. File Upload Exceeds Server Limit
5. Clear DNS Cache
6. Deactivate Browser Extensions

Regards,

Peter